# 2 divs to left, other divs to right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float 2 divs on left side and two div on right side. All divs I need to have in one parent div.

My CSS:

```
.news { 
  width:50%; 
  float:right !important; 
}
.news:first-child {
    float:left;
}
.news:nth-child(2) {
    float:left;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="news">
    <img src="fileadmin/user_upload11150532_956775297674176_4405300320161350202_n.jpg">
    <h2>aaaaaa4</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <img src="fileadmin/user_upload11150532_956775297674176_4405300320161350202_n.jpg">
    <h2>aaaaaa4</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <img src="fileadmin/user_upload/11150532_956775297674176_4405300320161350202_n.jpg">
    <h2>aaaaaa4</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t93xT.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3nKN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take another element like

```css
.row{clear:both;}
.image {float:left;width:50%;}
.image-details {float:right;width:50%;}
.image img {display:block;height:auto;width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="image-details">some details <br>some details <br>some details <br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
    <div class="image-details">some details <br>some details <br>some details <br>some details <br></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on right side I've got another news, without image - it's not some details :-)

Comment: confusions please explain more i just make this example by seeing  your image

Answer (score 0):

Try this to distribute them left and right alternatingly:

```
.news:nth-child(odd) {
    float:left;
}
.news:nth-child(even) {
    float:right;
}
```